# Group Bar Chart Dinamic Data Update By Button Fuction ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have Data For My Chart Like This

**For Data**

```
var dataObject = [
  {
    label: ['1 Mouth', '2 Mouth', '3 Mouth', '4 Mouth', '5 Mouth', '6 Mouth', '7 Mouth'],
    datachart: [
      {
       label: 'Good',
       data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
       backgroundColor: '#f56954'
      },
      {
       label: 'Middle',
       data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
       backgroundColor: '#3c8dbc'
      },
      {
       label: 'Not Good',
       data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
       backgroundColor: '#74b32d'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: ['1 Mouth', '2 Mouth', '3 Mouth', '4 Mouth', '5 Mouth', '6 Mouth', '7 Mouth'],
    datachart: [
      {
       label: 'Good',
       data: [11,12,13,14,15,16,71],
       backgroundColor: '#f56954'
      },
      {
       label: 'Middle',
       data: [1,12,31,4,5,16,7],
       backgroundColor: '#3c8dbc'
      },
      {
       label: 'Not Good',
       data: [1,2,3,4,5,61,7],
       backgroundColor: '#74b32d'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

**For Chartjs**

```
var data = {
      labels: dataObject[0].label,
      datasets: dataObject[0].datachart
};
```

**How to update data according to dataObject variable? I've done this**

```
function changeData7(index) {
  chart7.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
    dataset.label = dataObject[index].label;
    dataset.data = dataObject[index].datachart;
  });
  chart7.update();
}
```

**but the data is not updated instead it is lost, whereas if I only use 1 data not a group, it is successfully updated**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're updating each dataset, and feeding it's `data` with the new dataset. Also, the labels should also be provided on the chart itself, instead of the dataset items.

The correct way would be

```
function changeData(index) {
    var data = dataObject[index];
    chart.data.labels = data.label;
    chart.data.datasets = data.datachart;
    chart.update();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8kzoc6nb/

Comment: Amazingly this works, but why is there no data transfer chart animation?

Comment: What do you mean with no animation? Chart.js default behaviour when updating charts is to  show a small animation changing the data. Can you provide a [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](minimal reproducible example)? I've edited my answer to add a jsfiddle you can edit

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeData7(index) {
  chart7.data.datasets.forEach(function(item, indexs) {
    item.label = dataObject[index].datachart[indexs].label;
    item.data = dataObject[index].datachart[indexs].data;
  });
  chart7.update();
}
```

I do this but if i call `changeData7(0)`, data doesnt change to index 0